# how do I go about suggesting a update to a tag name?

Tags: support, tags

There is a tag on one of the exchange site I use which is misleadingly named and has a good alternative. How to I suggest that edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to that site's Meta and post a new question requesting that it be changed. If it's not a straight-forward rename, then you'll want to include details and explanations for why the rename should occur. This can only be done by moderators, so you'll need to convince them well that it should be done.